# perl foreach loop skip iteration for specific file under specific folder

Tags: perl, foreach, iteration

I have perl script to exclude few paths from my processing. 
Now I want to add a new folder (`/foo/`) to the exclude path, everything under which should be excluded except a file name `Hello`

I know we can use keyword `next` to skip the loop , but how can I implement it just for one file under a specific folder?

folder `/foo/` can be inside any directory , like `abc/foo/def/` or `hij/klm/foo/`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @excludepaths = (
  "abc/def/",
  "hij/klm/",   
);


foreach (@excludepaths)
{
  if (SOME_TEST_CONDITION) # exclude filename "Hello" under "Foo" folder
   {
      # move on to the next loop element
      next;
   }

 # more code here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is - create a regular expression, and use the `|` to create an or condition.

So use your:

```
my @excludepaths = (
  "abc/def/",
  "hij/klm/",   
);
```

Turn this into a regex like so:

```
my $regex = join ( "|", map { quotemeta } @excludepaths ); 
   $regex = qr/($regex)/;
```

Then you should be able to do

```
next if m/$regex/;
```

So for example:

```
my @excludepaths = (
  "abc/def/",
  "hij/klm/",   
);

my $regex = join ( "|", @excludepaths ); 
   $regex = qr/($regex)/; 

for ( "abc/def/ghk", "abf/de/cg", "abf/hij/klm/ghf", "fish/bat/mix" ) {
   next if m/$regex/;
   print;
   print "\n";
}
```

If you do that, you can add any pattern you like to your 'exclude' simply by adding it to the list.

So you can add `/foo/.*/Hello$` and it'll skip a match on:

```
/some/path/to/foo/and/more/Hello
```

Because regex paths are substring matches.

Edit: Based on your comments:

```
my @excludepaths = ( "abc/def/", "hij/klm/", "/foo/", );

my $regex = join( "|", @excludepaths );
$regex = qr/($regex)/;

my $include_regex = qr,/foo/.*\bHELLO$,;

for (
    "abc/def/ghk",              "abf/de/cg",
    "abf/hij/klm/ghf",          "fish/bat/mix",
    "/path/with/foo/not/HELLO", "/path/with/foo/",
    "/path/with/foo/HELLO"
    )
{
    next if ( m/$regex/ and not m/$include_regex/ );
    print;
    print "\n";
}
```

We explicitly exclude anything containing `/foo/` but override with `$include_regex` such that `/path/with/foo/not/HELLO` still passes the filer.

Comment: Your code excludes the whole directories listed in `@excludepaths`. But I want to exclude all those except , if there is a directory `/foo/` then ignore a file name `HELLO` in that and exclude rest all

Comment: Ah, ok. Misunderstood what you were looking for. Exceptions to your exclusion, right? So your test condition is effectively `unless m,/foo/.*/Hello,`?

Comment: @Sorbique : Will the `$include_regex` condition still holds good if the path is `/some/path/to/foo/Hello` ? If the file `Hello` is just under the folder `foo`?

Comment: Well spotted, yes - that'll break, because it'd need to be `foo//HELLO`. Amended code - should work now.

Comment: One should use quotemeta <http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html> so special characters in strings are escaped: `my $regex = join ( "|", map { quaotemeta } @excludepaths );`